# Spring boot POST rest API + Swagger UI: Http 415 Unsupported Media Type While Uploading a file along with a JSON object as POJO

Tags: spring-boot, file, post, swagger-ui

I'm implementing a Swagger UI to expose an existing POST REST API.
The Rest API is used to POST a person data (JSON Object) along with a File related

here is the Post method from the Rest Controller:

```
@Operation(summary = "Upload a document for a person")
@PostMapping(value = "/personEndpoint/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> savePerson(@RequestPart PersonDTO person, @RequestPart MultipartFile document) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String personId = personService.storePersonData(person, document);
        if (null != personId) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode json = mapper.readTree("{\"personId\": \"" + personId + "\"}");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(json);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error occurred while processing the request");
        }
}
```

The post is working fine with Postman if I specifically define the person content type as **application/json**
[image]

But, with Swagger Ui, I'm getting a **http 415 error (Unsupported Media Type)** (as shown in the following picture)

[image]

I'm using **Springboot** 3.0.2 With **springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui** 2.1.0 for swagger UI

here is my Swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Person REST Service", version = "1.0.0", description = "Person managment Services"))
public class SwaggerConfig {

}
```

Do I need a specific configuration to make this endpoint work on Swagger UI?

NB: I don't want to define the person JSON as a String in my Endpoint because I want it to be display as a Text Area on SwaggerUi

Please which configuration do I need I order to make this Endpoint working on Swagger UI?

Thanks so much